# login to SharePoint using WebServices to a non-FBA server

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, webservice-client

i'm writing a SharePoint client and i'm trying to login to the SharePoint Server using WebServices.
it's a SharePoint 2010 Server.

i'm using this WebService: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/authentication(office.12).aspx

when using this webservice i get this error: **NotInFormsAuthenticationMode**

i can't change anything on the server side, and the docs says this webservice is:
*Specifies a type of logon error for SharePoint sites that use **forms-based authentication**.*

my question is how do i login using webservies to a non-FBA SharePoint server

thank you

Comment: it uses Windows-Based authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved.
there is no need to use Login webservice.
just send credentials with http request when soaping webservice..

Comment: Hi Arbel, Can you please share the way you called soap request.